# General value of sine and cosine

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If
\begin{align*}
\cos(k \pi)=(-1)^k,\quad \text{and}\quad \sin(k \pi)=0,
\end{align*}then can we find generalized expressions for
\begin{align*}
\cos(\frac{k \pi}{n}),\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{Z^+}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\sin(\frac{k \pi}{n}),\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{Z^+}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What do you mean by "generalized expression"?

Comment: for example $\cos(k \pi)=(-1)^k$. I am looking for same kind of expression.

Comment: Hm... if this were possible, then the cosine and sine functions wouldn't exist. There would be no need for them.

Comment: If $\cos(k \pi)=(-1)^k$, then for $\cos(\frac{k \pi}{n})$ is not possible? I think there should be some formula for it......

Comment: ...maybe for specific $n$, but not a general formula for any $n$ at all. You would have to obtain exact values for *every conceivable value* of the cosine function... but this just can't be done; it has to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 5):

This may not be the best possible answer, but a relatively comprehensive one is given in the short article [Sines and Cosines for Fractions of $\pi$](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cds/articles/trig.pdf) by [Dr. Colin Steele at The University of Manchester](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cds/).

To paraphrase the article, "$\sin\frac{\pi}{n}$ and $\cos\frac{\pi}n$ can be found for $n=2^k\times3^p\times5^q\times17^r\times257^s\times65537^t$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer and the other indices are all $0$ or $1$." Once you have these values you can use [angle sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) to get other numerators.

For example, $\cos\frac{13\pi}{30}=\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}$.

Comment: $\cos \frac{\pi}{7} = \frac{-1}{24}(-4+\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{(448+\sqrt{-5419008})/2}+\frac{112}{\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\sqrt[3]{(448+\sqrt{-5419008})/2})})$ by Cardano's formula.

Comment: @sharding4 Good point, you're certainly right. Maybe Dr. Steele was trying to avoid things like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis) where we have to use complex numbers to represent these values (which applies here since all three zeros of, say, $8x^3-4x^2-4x+1$ are real). But maybe skorpion is interested in answers like that as well, so I would recommend you write out an answer that describes (and generalizes?) the method for finding that.

Answer (score 3):

In general $$\cos n\theta= \cos^n \theta- \frac {n (n-1)}{2!} \cos^{n-2}\theta \sin^2 \theta+\cdots $$ 
$$ \sin n\theta =n cos^{n-1}\theta sin \theta-\frac {n (n-1)(n-2)}{3!} cos^{n-3}\theta sin^3\theta+\cdots$$
Here take $k=n $ and $\theta=\frac {\pi}{n} $.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *no, you can't*.

Perhaps for specific values of $n$ you could do this, like with your example
$$\cos(k\pi)=(-1)^k, \forall k \in \mathbb Z$$
In fact, you could probably do this for a lot of $n$. However, you will never find a way to do so for *all $n$*, because the whole purpose of the sine and cosine functions is to act as a placeholder for the infinite number of values that cannot be expressed in terms of other elementary functions. The closest thing that I can think of would be to use the fact that
$$\cos x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!}x^{2i+1}$$
to say that
$$\cos \frac{k\pi}{n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!}\bigg(\frac{k\pi}{n}\bigg)^{2i+1}$$
... but that's not even closed form, so I don't think it's what you're looking for.